# Login player name is not displaying in the titel of Navigation bar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display login player `FullName` in the top right of the navigation bar. In may Xamarin Forms app, I am using tabbed pages to display Home, Map, Settings, Daily Count tabs created via code ( don't have separate navigation.xaml). 
Below is Home screen, would like to display the name in the space where I have marked in the screenshot.

In the `GetLoginPlayerName()` method I can see `details` is assigned to  `loginPlayer.Text = details.ToString()`, but still I am unable to see player FullName in the navigation space. Could some one please advise how can I fix this ?

Below is the Home.xaml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
                 x:Class="soccerapp.Home" BackgroundColor="White" Title="Home">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#D60000">        
            <Label x:Name="loginPlayer" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <ContentPage.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="playerTemplate">
                <ContentView>
                    <StackLayout  Margin="5,5" BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
                        <Label Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Mobile}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SoccerPosition}"/>
                        <Button Text="Remove Player"  Clicked="DeleteButton_OnClicked" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50"  TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPage.Resources>
        <StackLayout Margin="5">
            <CollectionView x:Name="collectionview"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource playerTemplate}">
                <!--span here decides the number of items shows in one line. Now is 3 items one line-->
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

See the below code in Home.xaml.cs

```cs
    namespace soccerapp
    {
        [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class Home : ContentPage
        {
            public SQLiteConnection conn = null;
            ObservableCollection<PlayerDetails> players;
            string loginEmail;

            public Home(string email)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                conn = DependencyService.Get<Isqlite>().GetConnection();
                conn.CreateTable<PlayerDetails>();
                players = new ObservableCollection<PlayerDetails>();
                collectionview.ItemsSource = players;
                loginEmail = email;
                GetLoginPlayerName();
                DisplayDetails();
            }

            public void GetLoginPlayerName()
            {
                int count = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(x => x.Email == loginEmail) select x).Count();
                if (count!= 0)
                {
                    var details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>()
                                   where x.Email == loginEmail
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Name = x.FullName

                                   }).ToList();
                    loginPlayer.Text = details.ToString();

                }

            }

            public void DisplayDetails()
            {
                List<PlayerDetails> details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() select x).ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < details.Count; i++)
                {
                    players.Add(details[i]);
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a root navigation page wrap all of your contents including the Tabbed Page. It caused your title view dismissing, as the current title view you want to display is belong to Tabbed Page instead of Home Page.

So I recommend you to adjust your project's architecture:
[image]

Set your tabbed page as the root page and make each of its children wrapped by a Navigation page. Then you could handle the title view in your current Home page.

Comment: Can you show an example for tabbed page set in Navigation

Comment: @soccerway Here is my sample: https://github.com/landl0526/TabbedDemo.git

Comment: @Lu,..I understood that it might be a huge change in my architecture ..need to change some many places I guess. Apart from this do we have any other way ?

Comment: @soccerway You could change the parent tabbed page's title view to display your label. But once you have done that, the other tab's title view was also changed. So I don't recommend you to do that.

Comment: @Lu, Thanks ..will try to blend the navigation as you suggested...don't know if it work

Comment: @soccerway Actually, I prefer to make the tabbed page as the App's main page instead of pushing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193748/discussion-between-soccerway-and-land-lu-msft).

Comment: Lu -Could you help me in one my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405016/system-throws-unable-to-get-file-exception-even-file-path-and-permissions-are-pr

Answer (score 1):

your query returns a list which you are trying to assign to a Label - this won't work.  Instead, try returning just the first item that matches

```
var detail = conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().First(x => x.Email == loginEmail);
loginPlayer.Text = detail.FullName;
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, now the query is returning the name, but I am not able to see the name in the Navigation area.

Comment: if you hardcode a value in your Label XAML does it display?

Comment: No its not displaying either, I have tried `<Label x:Name="loginPlayer" Text="HardcodeText" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>`

Comment: Try assigning a HeightRequest value

Comment: I have tried the like this `<Label x:Name="loginPlayer" Text="SomeName" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="20"/>`, gave HeightRequest=20, but still no difference